# Catel Auto Register Attributes with multiple instances

Tags: catel

we are developing a GUI Plug-In Framework using Catel.MVVM.
Single Plugins should be loaded dynamically using the "ServiceLocatorRegistration" Attribute.

Example:

```
[ServiceLocatorRegistration(typeof(IInitializable), ServiceLocatorRegistrationMode.SingletonInstantiateWhenRequired, "SamplePlugin")]
```

In our bootstrapper we load all Plugin assemblies into the default AppDomain:

```
      Catel.Windows.Controls.MVVMProviders.Logic.UserControlLogic.DefaultSkipSearchingForInfoBarMessageControlValue = true;
      Catel.Windows.Controls.MVVMProviders.Logic.UserControlLogic.DefaultCreateWarningAndErrorValidatorForViewModelValue = false;

      IoCConfiguration.DefaultServiceLocator.AutoRegisterTypesViaAttributes = true;
      IoCConfiguration.DefaultServiceLocator.CanResolveNonAbstractTypesWithoutRegistration = true;

      foreach (
        var file in
          BaseDirectory.GetFiles("*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(f => IsNetAssembly(f.FullName))
            .Where(f => !f.FullName.EndsWith("resources.dll"))
            .AsParallel())
      {
        try
        {
          var asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(file.FullName);
        }
        catch { }
      }
```

Then we try to initialize them by calling

```
var initializables = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveTypes();
foreach(var initializable in initializables)
  initializable.Initialize();
```

But even if we have the plugin assemblies loaded in the AppDomain, we dont get all Classes with the ServiceLocatorRegistration attribute.

Is there any was to resolve all classes that have the example attribute set as above?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably because the assemblies containing the types that use the registration are not loaded into the AppDomain yet. There are a few things you can consider:

1) Use [AppDomainExtensions.PreloadAssemblies](https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/b965da88b7035117757368090d5be38c1825035b/src/Catel.Core/Catel.Core.NET40/Reflection/Extensions/AppDomainExtensions.cs#L63)

2) Use the type somehow (like Console.WriteLine(typeof(TypeFromAssembly).FullName))

I wouldn't recommend the second one because it goes against your plug-in architecture.

Comment: I will try it asap (1st one), but as i wrote - we already load the assemblies into the default AppDomain.
I added the corresponding code in my question above.
May the problem be that we load the assemblies "ReflectionOnly"?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue myself. Mistake was probably the line`var asm = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(file.FullName);`
After replacing this line with`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.LoadAssemblyIntoAppDomain(file.FullName);` everything works as expected.
Thanks Geert for pointing to the right direction!